# Using Support libraries when developing for Android 4.1 and higher

Tags: android, android-support-library

The current `minSdkVersion` for my app is `16`, `targetSdkVersion`,`compileSdkVersion` are `21`.

When I first started the app, `minSdkVersion` was `10`, and the book I was learning from used the v4 Support library.

I've gone through my app and I found that these are the imports I have been using from the v4 support library:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle
DialogFragment
DrawerLayout
Fragment
FragmentActivity
FragmentManager
FragmentStatePagerAdapter
ListFragment
NavUtils
ViewPager
```

Since I have raised the `minSdkVersion`, I don't think I need to use the support versions of most of these anymore. I believe I still have to use `ViewPager` and `DrawerLayout`, though.

The [developer](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#using-apis) pages say:

> Caution: When using classes from the Support Library, be certain you import the class from the appropriate package.
>
> For example, when applying the ActionBar class:
>
> android.support.v7.app.ActionBar when using the Support Library.
>
> android.app.ActionBar when developing only for API level 11 or higher.

So, my question is:

1) May I simply use an import similar to `android.app.Fragment` for all of the above, since my API level is minimum 16? (Except `ViewPager` and `DrawerLayout`)

2) For `ViewPager` and `DrawerLayout`, is there a difference between using v4 or v7 or another support library version?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, with `Fragment` and all its related paraphernalia (`FragmentManager`, `FragmentTransaction`, &c) the most important thing is to use the imports **consistently** (that is, don't mix and match). That, I think, is the point the documentation wants to make.

That said...

You *could* swap out usages of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `android.app.Fragment` if you wanted to use the native versions of these classes instead of the support ones, but be careful: the support library also adds some methods and callbacks that were not present in API level 16 (one important example being [`getChildFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29). So, basically, it comes down to whether all the features of Fragments that you're using are available for the native Fragments in all the API levels you will support.

Also, using the support library Fragments means that they should behave *exactly the same* in all Android versions, while they might be differences in the native implementations.

In our particular case we decided to keep using the support library, but YMMV.

As for the second question, I don't think there is a v7-specific ViewPager (at least, I think so). The v7 libraries are add-ons (appcompat, gridlayout, &c).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think my app is using any methods that would not be compatible with the native versions. But if I later have to switch back to the support versions, are there any drawbacks to using the support library versions (apart from additional dependencies)?

Comment: @OnThisDayFiftyYearsAgo Not particularly. I think it might be preferable too, as you'd be running the same Fragment code in all android versions.

Comment: There is a good point to keep using v7 support library is that they update the lib to support the latest android 5.0 (many of so many) feartures. So once you integrated the libs in your project, all you have to do is to update your gradle setting. I would like to recommend you to use support v7 libs. FYI v7 is using v4 in some case.